# TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/regist_save/ error

Tags: python, django

I got a error .
I think urls.py or templates is wrong,but I do not know how to fix it.
Furthermore,I think urls.py & templates do not have any bad point.How can I fix them?
I wrote in urls.py,

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,name='regist' ),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
]
```

in views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('registration/accounts/profile.html', context)


    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)
```

in profile.html (templates)

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        user.username : {{ user.username }}<hr>
        user.is_staff: {{ user.is_staff }}<hr>
        user.is_active: {{ user.is_active }}<hr>
        user.last_login : {{ user.last_login }}<hr>
        user.date_joined: {{ user.date_joined }}
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Apparently the template here: `'accounts/regist.html'` does not actually exist. Is that the proper path to the template?

Comment: your file tree and the debugging trackback on the webpage? Django has awesome debugging info . Try read that